# What is SUID bit used for

Tags: linux, file-permissions, suid

From what I read "SUID bit gives other users the ability to run a file with the permissions of the file owner" 
So I did this
2 users : user1 & user2
User 1 creates a script

```
#/bin/bash
touch /home/user1/file1
```

User 1 does a chmod 4777 on the script (giving all users full access)

Now user2 tries to run the script and fails. No permissions!

Shouldn't the script run with the permissions of user1?

If SUID is purely for commands present in sbin then what is the difference between setting the SUID bit and adding all users to the suoder file with permissions for a specific command?

Answer (score 4):

SUID and SGID *generally* don't work on scripts. They are used to run *compiled executables* as another user/group. Some interpreters (e.g. Perl) will detect the bits and run a separate interpreter executable in order to switch to the user, but most do not.